# Working on a remote package locally in Go

Tags: go

I have a package which I want to access from another part of my code, that package is imported with the path like `github.com/my-project/service`. To work with that I have to push the code on github, then I have to update my go.mod, which doesn't really work if I'm actively coding on the service package.
I made it possible to work on my local by adding a replace on my local `replace github.com/my-project/service => ../service`, but then if I push the go.mod file on my server, it will fail because `../service` doesn't exist. I know I shouldn't commit replace directives, so is the only solution to remember to comment out the replace on every single commits?
Is there a way to solve this issue, or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: "am I just doing it wrong?" This. do not commit replace directives and do not push them.

Comment: @Volker I understand I shouldn't push the replace directive, but you're not replying to the question. How do people do it? Do you just remove the replace every time you do a commit? That doesn't seem very practical!

Comment: No, they just don't `git add go.mod` before doing a commit. Or do it interactively.

Comment: @Volker So you're saying that you never push go.mod at all? How does the server know what package version to use? Can you help me out with this concept, because I use go.mod for package updates on the server, you're saying that it has to be done differently?

Comment: No, of course not. All I said: "Do not push replace directives". There are several ways to not push replace directives and you are free to choose one to your liking.

Comment: @Volker Can you elaborate, because right now you're so ambiguous, I'm not sure you really understood the question...

Comment: I'm very sorry if I'm not clear. I understand your problem that you want to `replace` a module while working locally on your code. This is fine and what `replace` is for. Just do not commit these `replace` directives. How you don't commit them is of secondary importance. Whether you don't `git add` go.mod at all or just `git add -i go.mod` is totally up to you. If you didn't commit the replace directive you don't push them upstream naturally and all is good. Maybe you are overthinking something that basically is a triviality?

Comment: @Volker I understand what you're saying, but we have a few developers in the team, what you're saying is to place a memo for everybody saying "make sure every time you commit, either comment that replace if you're updating, or exclude it from git if you're not", at one point someone is going to forget. You see the issue? I want to make it so either we don't have any replace directive, or something else. I don't believe I'm the only one having this issue.

Comment: Then do _not_ use replace directives. There are several ways to not use them, e.g. by combining both modules into one larger module (lots of people working simultaneous on both modules at the same time is a _strong_ hint that these modules arn't independent but share a _common_ _lifecycle_ making them _one_ module; remember: a module is a set of packages with the same lifecycle, nothing more, nothing less). Or use a go.work file setting up a workspace. Probably a few more options that I can't think of right now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on relative paths and replace directives, you can set up Go Modules properly for your project. Start by initializing Go Modules in your project's root directory:

```
go mod init github.com/my-project
```

Then, import your package using its full module path:

```
import "github.com/my-project/service"
```

Go will use the local version of the package automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but what if another developer makes a change, would the update of the package crush the changes the first developer is working on?

Comment: If you update your go mod file then there's possibility to crush. You have to maintain Module versioning for that.